# Using Regex to remove html elements and leave the content

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have the following html

```
<b>Item 1</b> Text <br>
<b>Item 2</b> Text <br>
<b>Item 3</b> Text <br>
<p><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><b>Item 4:</b></font></p>
<p><font color="#000000" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Detailed Description</font></p>
```

and am using the following regex to capture data `(Item 1:.*?<br>)/gi` which returns `<b>Item 1</b> Text <br>`

How do i drop or remove the `<b>,</b> and <br>`

to be left with

> Item 1 Text

I've been trying to make sense of this code `<(\w+)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>`, but so far no luck. All the examples I have seen on here seem to require an id class, which my html does not have so i'm a bit stuck in getting those examples to fit my problem.

Comment: No, i'm looking for pure regex to be used in a javascript application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a regex, what is between () represents capture groups that can be later accessed as variables (\1 \2 \3 etc.) or sometimes $1 $2 $3. So simply use them to capture the text you want.

I think this regex would work for you:

```
<b>(Item \d+)</b>(.*?)<br>
```

in details, the expression means:

- `(Item \d+)`: Any string formatted as **"Item *[at least 1 digit]*"**
- `(.*?)`: any group of characters, the `?` minimizes the number of characters in the sequence.

So now in `<b>Item 5434</b>hel34lo 0345 345<br>`, with regex above your captured groups are:

- `\1` = Item 5434
- `\2` = hel34lo 0345 345

I've never programmed in javascript, but more precisely, this piece of code might work:

```
var myString = "<b>Item 5434</b>hel34lo 0345 345<br>";
var myRegexp = /<b>(Item \d+)</b>(.*?)<br>/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]); // Item 5434 
alert(match[2]); // hel34lo 0345 345
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this regex returns the same as my original code with the tags as well. I Need the end result to ignore those pesky bold and break tags

Comment: I've never programmed in javascript, but more precisely, this piece of code might work, which is using the same regex specified in my post:

var myString = "<b>Item 5434</b>hel34lo 0345 345<br>";
var myRegexp = /<b>(Item \d+)</b>(.*?)(?=<br>)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);  // Item 5434
alert(match[2]);  // hel34lo 0345 345

Comment: @DoesntMatter: if you want to provide code, please update your answer. Any code in the comments is hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

Try this reg ex: `<[^>]*>`

This will remove all the html with or without attributes and closing tags.

Comment: Thanks, This is one of the examples I have seen whilst searching but can't seem to get to work. How would you go about combining it with the `(Item 1:.*?<br>)/gi`. I need one line of code to retrieve the data and leave out the tags?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var matches = stringToTest.match(/(Item \d+.*?<br\/?>)/gi);
for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  matches[i] = matches[i].replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
}
alert(matches);
```

If you have jQuery:

```
alert(
    $.map(stringToTest.match(/(Item \d+.*?<br\/?>)/gi), function(v) { return v.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '') })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match **b** and **br** tags:

```
</?br?\s*/?>
```

To use it in Javascript you write something like this:

```
result = subject.replace(/<\/?br?\s*\/?>/img, "");
```

All the matched tags will be replaced with an empty string.

In my experience it is better to replace **br** tags with a space and replace normal inline tags with empty string. If that is what you want to do, this next regex matches only **b** tags:

```
</?b\s*/?>
```

and this one matches only **br** tags:

```
</?br\s*/?>
```